# Does text-align center and absolute positioning not work simultaneously in IE-11?

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, css-position, internet-explorer-11

The following script(https://jsfiddle.net/u9z76r6q/2/) doesn't center the image in IE-11:

```css
.container {
  display: block;
  width: 400px;
  height: 200px;
  text-align: center;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
span {
  position: absolute;
 
}
```

```html
<a href="#" class="container">
  <span>
    <img src="https://redarrowmedia.files.wordpress.com/2012/03/arrow-logo1.png" alt="" width="40px" height="40px">    
  </span>
  </a>
```

In all other modern browser the arrow image is centered. Is this a bug in Internet Explorer?

Comment: In my opinion Chrome/FF and IE are wrong. IE behaves like `left` was set to `0`  and Chrome/FF as if the element does not have a width. To be honest I could not find something about the combination of `text-align: center`  and `left: auto` in the specs, but out of the description in [CSS absolute and fixed positioning](https://www.w3.org/wiki/CSS_absolute_and_fixed_positioning) I would say that IE is definitely wrong, and Chrome/FF slightly.

Comment: funny, once it was only IE behaving this way .... where other browser did not mind text-align ... wich i do not understand why they should for an element out of the flow. So long ago, i took the habit to redefine left coordonates to have same behavior everywhere. just like any other safe reset in CSS

Comment: @GCyrillus Other browsers should mind text-align because `left` is `auto` here.

Answer (score 2):

Absolutely positioned element doesn't take parent's width, its width depends on content. Different results are because different browsers are differently positioning span. Add `width: 100%; left: 0;` to span.

UPD: Screenshot in Chrome:
[image]

Screenshot in IE: [image]

You can see in IE span is positioned to left while in Chrome to center.
Content of span is still aligned to center but span width is too small to see it! Add width to span and see content inside will be aligned to center.
Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/u9z76r6q/3/ 
Watch in IE

UPD2: Actually in Chrome span is also not in center. It behaves like `left: 50%;`. Its left border is in center.

Comment: How differently are they positioning it? `left:0` is always default value. And what does absolute position has to do with `text-align: center`?

Comment: Open your fiddle in chrome and in ie and open dev tools. You will see span is positioned differently.

Comment: Text-align: center doesn't affect absolutely positioned element itself, only its content.

Comment: In dev tools the span is absolutely positioned in IE-11, chrome and firefox. Also why does it matter whether absolutely position element take it's parent's width or not? I've not assigned span any width.

Comment: @user31782 the default value for `left` is not `0` but `auto` that is  difference.

Comment: @t.niese When `right` is `auto` then `left:auto` and `left:0` both are same thing.

Comment: @user31782 no `left: auto` and `left:  0` are not the same thing, even if `right` is `auto`, it might have the same effect, but is definitely not the same. Take a look at this example: [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/a9hmL50v/2/). Here `right` is `auto`  but the position is different for  `left: auto` and `left:  0` (the same is with `top`). For your example `left: 0` should not center the `span`, but for `left: auto` it should be.

Comment: @t.niese Seems like `left: auto` respects the margin. Or in other words `left: auto` doesn't force the element to move to `left:0`.

Comment: There was no need to add the screen shots. I know that in IE the span is _position_ to the left. What I meant is that the computed style is `position: absolute`.

Comment: @user31782 The reason is explained in the specs and here [CSS absolute and fixed positioning](https://www.w3.org/wiki/CSS_absolute_and_fixed_positioning) `[...]the absolutely positioned box didn’t move. The default value for the top, right, bottom and left properties is auto, which means the absolutely positioned box will appear exactly where it would have had if it wasn’t positioned. Since it’s removed from the flow it will overlap any elements in the normal flow that follow it, though.[...]`  with `0` you set a position, with `auto` you don't.

Comment: @t.niese Means it is taken out of the flow but is positioned at it's original position untill we specify `left, top, bottom,` or `right`. IE is certainly buggy. Without `position: absolute` on the span the span is centered then as per the docs after `position: absolute` the span should be still at its original position.

Comment: @user31782 Well I added screenshot to show WHY span is appeared in different positions. Because it helps to understand how to solve the problem - make span be in same position in all browsers. You didn't specify that you don't need the cross-browser solution and only are searching for browser bugs :P

Comment: @Julia I just had simply used `left: 50%` on span and then `left:-50%` on image to center it. After this I took the pain to think about the bug in IE :-)

Comment: @user31782 does the above code works differently in IE? Anyway, using `left: 50%; transform: translateX(-50%);` will center span in all modern browsers. (Again i think about solution, not about bug. Sorry, freelancer's habit :D)

Comment: No it works the same in IE. But I think `translateX(-50%)` could be problematic in older browsers.